# Trouble with convert integer to date+time in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, type-conversion

i have in table one column in integer. This integer looks like:

`2204010044` - it is `YYMMDDHH24MI`.

I want this column in sql query convert to date. But when i try, i get error:
`ORA-01840`.
I testing this: `TO_DATE("mycolumn",'yymmddhh24mi')`
I've tried multiple options, but always to no avail.

`NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is for database: `DD.MM.YY` (i dont know,if its relevant)

Comment: `to_date` takes a string as input, so number gets implicitly converted to string. Please validate the value of `to_char("mycolumn")`. It should work anyway: see [db_fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hpOWo-al)

Comment: What means year `22`? Did you never hear about the famous [Y2K-Bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe with something like this:

```
select to_timestamp(cast(2204010044 as varchar(10)),'YYMMDDHH24MI') 
from dual
```

If you want to keep the time, you must cast to timestamp, not date.

If you want just the date, use:

```
select to_date(2204010044,'YYMMDDHH24MI') 
from dual
```

You can test on this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OjOndkUD)

Comment: when I try it on the given column, it gives me this: `ORA-01840:input value not long enough for date format` . I don know...the column has exactly the format I described, so I don't know why it reports this.

Comment: EDIT: You are right...when designing the database, the whitespace was not covered. Solved. Thank you.

Comment: "If you want to keep the time, you must cast to timestamp, not date" - that's not right; Oracle dates always have the time (down to seconds), even if your client doesn't display it by default - [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rCOtXIfB).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following SQL query:

```
select TO_DATE(2204010044,'yymmdd hh24:MI:ss')
  FROM dual
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/26B4ekNI)

Comment: a similar case to that of a colleague below: when I try it on the given column, it gives me this: `ORA-01840:input value not long enough for date format`

Comment: check the NLS_DATE_FORMAT, it looks like the SQL query works. See the link https://dbfiddle.uk/26B4ekNI

Comment: EDIT: You are right...when designing the database, the whitespace was not covered. Solved. Thank you.